# Iterating over Django model attributes

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-1.7, django-1.8

I have a class defined like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
...
```

I have an instance of this class and I would like to iterate over it's meta attributes:

```
opts = instance._meta
for f in opts.many_to_many + opts.concrete_fields + opts.virtual_fields:
    ...
```

This code works perfectly with Django 1.7, but doesn't work with Django 1.8.
The error I'm receiving is a type error and it's value is:
`can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple`

What can be the problem with it?

Comment: The problems is that some of the attributes are tuples and some are lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `opts.virtual_fields` type. It is `list` now. I guess it was changed in 1.8

To solve it:

```
metas = opts.concrete_fields + opts.many_to_many + tuple(opts.virtual_fields)
```